# How to delete a file present in some directory in linux programmatically

Tags: java, linux, delete-file

My aim is to delete a file in some directory present in linux using a java program. I have the following line that does that:

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/rm -f " + fileToDelete.getAbsolutePath());
```

But I read that using linux commands from java program would be a costlier operation. Could anyone let me know if there is another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [`File#delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29)

```
boolean isFileDeleted = fileToDelete.delete();
```

Comment: I see from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path) taht "On some operating systems it may not be possible to remove a file when it is open and in use by this Java virtual machine or other programs" in that case I may need to force delete this file even if its open. I think "rm -f" does that. How to achieve that?

Comment: I would not recommend deleting open files. What if there is remaining unwritten data? I would suggest to ensure all open files are closed first. Remember it is in _this_ JVM so you will have control over this

Comment: From what I remember Windows will block the deletion of open files but Linux won't. Have you tried deleting an open file like this?

Comment: @user2349990, on Linux there is no problem in deleting an open file, and `File.delete` will call the same operating system function as the `rm` command, but will be a lot less expensive. The `-f` option only makes `rm` ignore files that don't exist; usually it would report an error.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `File` object, as such:

```
// initializes your file with your full path (or use your "fileToDelete" variable)
File file = new File("myFile");
// attempts to set the file writable and returns boolean result
System.out.println("Could set file writable: " + file.setWritable(true));
// attempts to delete the file and returns boolean result
System.out.println("Deleted succesfullly: " + file.delete());
```

Permission / delete operations may throw an unchecked `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file.exists())
    boolean isSuccessful = file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in my Linux

```
File f= new File("Path");
try {
    java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -f " + f.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```